# Converting PHP array manipulation to Ruby hashes

Tags: php, ruby, arrays, hash

I've written this script to be run in PHP, and am trying to convert it to Ruby.

Code:

```
$cases = array();


foreach($results as $result)
{
    if(!array_key_exists($result['id'], $cases))
        $cases[$result['id']] = array($result);
    else
        $cases[$result['id']][] = $result;
}

foreach($cases as $key => $case)
{
    foreach($case as $payment)
    {
        if(count($case) > 1)
        {

            $cases[$key]['total'] += ($payment['p1'] > $payment['p2']) ? $payment['p1'] : $payment['p2'];

        } else {

            $cases[$key]['total'] = ($payment['p1'] > $payment['p2']) ? $payment['p1'] : $payment['p2'];
        }
    }
}
```

In Ruby, I have the results as an array returned by MySQL (using `mysql2` gem).  Using the loop below, it prints every row.  How can I check if the key exists when it does not provide keys?

What's the best way to implement this code in Ruby?  How can I add a hash onto a hash in Ruby similar to adding an array onto an array in PHP.

```
results.each(:as => :array) do |row|
    puts row.inspect
end
```

More explanation:

PHP Structure

```
Array(
    0 => Array(
        Array(
            [id] => 'random id',
            [p1] => 534,
            [p2] => 105
        ),
        Array(
            [id] => 'random id',
            [p1] => 335,
            [p2] => 425
        )
    ),
    1 => Array(
        Array(
            [id] => 'random id',
            [p1] => 259,
            [p2] => 124
        )
    )
)
```

And i'm trying to iterate over each array inside the first, and if p1 > p2, add p1 to the total key on that array.  i.e., the 0 index would look like this:

```
0 => Array(
    'total' => 959,
    Array(
        [id] => 'random id',
        [p1] => 534,
        [p2] => 105
    ),
    Array(
        [id] => 'random id',
        [p1] => 335,
        [p2] => 425
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to group by `result['id']`? I believe that "translating" your PHP code to ruby will look something like this:

```
cases = {}
results.each do |result|
  if cases[result['id']]
    cases[result['id']] << result
  else
    cases[result['id']] = [result]
  end
end
```

Another way to get the same result is to use [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
cases = results.group_by { |result| result['id'] }
```

The second part "translated" to ruby will look something like this:

```
cases.each do |key, c|
  c.each do |payment|
    if c.count > 1 
      c['total'] += (payment['p1'] > payment['p2']) ? payment['p1'] : payment['p2']
    else
      c['total'] = (payment['p1'] > payment['p2']) ? payment['p1'] : payment['p2']
    end
  end
end
```

(this will actually not work in ruby, since an array cannot have an arbitrary key like `'total'` - it accepts only numbers in its brackets. You will have to modify this code to hold the totals in a different structure)

Again, a more idiomatic way of summing up the max between `'p1'` and `'p2'` of each payment in each case might look more like this:

```
totals = cases.values.map do |c|
  c.inject(0) { |sum, payment| sum + [payment['p1'], payment['p2']].max }
end
```

Comment: That's only the first part.

Comment: @nmm59 - added the other part